# Standard HTML editing tools don't parse Razor; designers delete my code. How to solve this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, lorem-ipsum

I'm setting up a proof-of-concept site and it seems that standard web design software doesn't hide the Razor syntax (which isn't a suprise).  What does bother me is that my overzealous designers will delete these code blocks and replace it with Lorem Ipsum text.

This worked fine with the ASPX syntax, since the angle brackets hid my code, but now the Razor format seems to be causing more trouble than it's worth.

Is anyone using Razor in a similar environment (1 or more devs, 1 or more designers)?

What does Microsoft expect from Razor in regard to web designers?

Comment: Just a untested thought - Wrap Razor in ASP.NET-style brackets? ...or HTML brackets if Razor is smart enough to remove them...

Comment: We're currently using Razor for a few upcoming projects at my place of business. To prevent this type of stuff I've developed a quick Syntax HIghlighter that allows those that aren't familiar with Razor to quickly recognize it from html by adding a background to the c#. This still won't solve your problem in people replacing it but it helps to educate them. Then using svn (or any other source control) you can easily revert when accidental changes are made.

Comment: Right after I posted that Microsoft released the RC for MVC 3 which includes syntax highlighting and intellisense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to handle this is to sit down with the designers and show them the razor syntax. These days, designers and programmers really need to work together on web apps, being ignorant of each others roles is not the best scenario.